# DocumentDB SQL with ARRAY_CONTAINS

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm playing around on https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo, which allows me to query against sample documents that look like:

```
{
  "id": "19015",
  "description": "Snacks, granola bars, hard, plain",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "snacks"
    }
  ],
  "version": 1,
  "isFromSurvey": false,
  "foodGroup": "Snacks",
  "servings": [
    {
      "amount": 1,
      "description": "bar",
      "weightInGrams": 21
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm confused about `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. This query returns results:

```
SELECT root
FROM root 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.tags, { "name": "snacks" })
```

However, this query does not:

```
SELECT root
FROM root 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.servings, { "description": "bar" })
```

What gives?

What I'm trying to achieve is illustrated by how I would write the query if this was C#:

```
var filteredDocs = docs.Where(d => d.Servings != null &&
                                   d.Servings.Length > 0 &&
                                   d.Servings.Any(s => s.Description == "bar"));
```

It appears the first example query on `root.tags` works because `{ "name": "snacks" }` is the *entire* object in the `root.tags` array, while, in the second query, `{ "description": "bar" }` is only *one field* in the `root.servings` objects.

How can I modify the second query on `root.servings` to work with only knowing the serving `description`?

Comment: The reason `tags` matches, and `servings` doesn't is that `ARRAY_CONTAINS` appears to be an exact match. So it's looking for a serving object that only has a description. Here's an example of it working if you specify the full object: https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20%09food%0AFROM%20%09food%0AWHERE%20%09ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.nutrients,%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22:%20%22612%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%2214:0%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22nutritionValue%22:%200.088,%0A%20%20%20%20%22units%22:%20%22g%22%0A%20%20%7D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: ARRAY_CONTAINS now supports partial match as Jim Scott points out below, which I think is a better answer than this accepted one.

You `servings` array only has one entry `{"amount": 1, "description": "bar", "weightInGrams": 21}`.

This should work for your example with a single serving:

```
SELECT root
FROM root 
WHERE root.servings[0].description = "bar"
```

But it sounds like that's not what you are looking for. So, assuming you have this:

```
{
  ...
  "servings": [
    {"description": "baz", ....},
    {"description": "bar", ....},
    {"description": "bejeweled", ....}
  ],
  ...
}
```

And you want to find the documents where one of the servings has the description "bar", then you could use this UDF:

```
function(servings, description) {
    var s, _i, _len;
    for (_i = 0, _len = servings.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        s = servings[_i];
        if (s.description === description) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this query:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE udf.findServingsByDescription(c.servings, "bar")
```

Comment: What if my `servings` had ten entries and I wanted all `root`s where at least one entry has `description = "bar"`?

Comment: Can you edit the question with an example showing 2 or 3 and your expected output?

Comment: I am still confused as to why ARRAY_CONTAINS works for tags but does not work for, say, the nutrients array:


SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.nutrients, { id: "287" })

This to me looks like the exact same query.  Only difference is that a nutrients element has more than one value (id, description, nutritionValue, units) while tags only has "name".

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether or not it's a tag. `ARRAY_CONTAINS` expects an array of JSON base types (String, Number) rather than an Object. So, an array of tags (`["High", "Medium"]`) meets that requirement as does an array of Numbers (`[1, 4, 7]`) whereas your example does not.

Comment: `ARRAY_CONTAINS` limitation is that it only works on simple value types, not objects - you need to either use a `JOIN` or **UDF**

Comment: @SliverNinja `ARRAY_CONTAINS` works on complex types too, but it's an exact match, so you have to specify the entire object. https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20%09food%0AFROM%20%09food%0AWHERE%20%09ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.nutrients,%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22:%20%22612%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%2214:0%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22nutritionValue%22:%200.088,%0A%20%20%20%20%22units%22:%20%22g%22%0A%20%20%7D)

Answer (score 28):

Not sure if this functionality was available when you were looking at the API originally but the [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) now supports an optional Boolean value at the end to provide partial match support.

```
SELECT root
FROM root
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.servings, { "description": "bar" }, true)
```

Here is sample using the [documentdb demo site](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20%09food%0AFROM%20%09food%0AWHERE%20%09ARRAY_CONTAINS(food.nutrients,%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22:%20%22612%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%2214:0%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22nutritionValue%22:%200.088,%0A%20%20%20%20%22units%22:%20%22g%22%0A%20%20%7D)) that queries an array that contains multiple fields for each object stored.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    food as f
WHERE   ARRAY_CONTAINS(f.servings, {"description":"bar"}, true)
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that this is a workaround that works fine.

```
SELECT c.id FROM c JOIN a in c.companies where a.id = '{id}'
```

In Linq this would be

```
x => x.companies.Any(z => z.id == id)
```

Comment: I upvoted because I think you are correct but it would improve your answer if you used the field names in the original example.

Answer (score 4):

Using a UDF, as Larry Maccherone mentioned, has the disadvantage that it does not use the collection's index. A UDF should only be used in (very) small collections or in combination with criteria that use the collection's index.

A good solution for this problem is currently missing in DocumentDB. I would advice to vote on the following item:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/14829654-support-sub-query-functions-like-exists-not-exist