# Cosmos db sql query for search in array

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document structure like below

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "author": "John Smith",
        "partNames": [
            "PART.5",
            "PART.10",
            "PART.15",
            "PART.30",
            "PART.31"
        ]
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "author": "Mike Smith",
        "partNames": [
            "PART.4",
            "PART.6",
            "PART.17",
            "PART.18",
            "PART.20"
        ]
        ...
    }
]
```

and I try to implement searching for user by fields author and partNames, so user can do query like

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.author, 'John')`

and user will get in result the `id=1` document because the name of author was `John`.

The next step is to allow user ask for document by parts, so for example I want to receive a document where `PART.4` exists, so the query will be

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.partNames, 'PART.4', true)`

and it returns document `id=2`.

Going further I'd like to make query that allows user to type just `PART.1` and he will receive documents `id=1` and `id=2` because both have parts starting with `PART.1`

So is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test below sql:

```
SELECT distinct value c FROM c
join p in c.partNames
where STARTSWITH(p, "PART.1")
```

Results:

[image]

---

Updates:

Op changed a little bit array because instead of `[part.1, part2...]` items and made another structure like `[ {part: part.1}, {part: part.2} ... ]` and managed to do query using user defined function similar to described here [DocumentDB SQL with ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137136/documentdb-sql-with-array-contains?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it works fine.

Comment: looks cool, however I changed a little bit array because instead of [part.1, part2...] items i made another structure like [ {part: part.1}, {part: part.2} ... ] and managed to do query using user defined function similar to described here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137136/documentdb-sql-with-array-contains?noredirect=1&lq=1
and it works fine, but maybe I'll return to your solution. Depends on needs. Thanks!

Comment: @Vrangz It's ok. Sounds you are using udf in your sql.Anyway,glad to see you already passed through. If you don't mind, i summarized your solution in my answer so that you could accept the answer to end this case.Thank you.